# How can I get error highlighting for missing imports in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

When working with Visual Studio Code on Windows to develop Angular applications, I recall that if I removed an import statement, vscode would almost immediately underline in red all of the places where those artifacts were being referenced.

However, now I am working in vscode on a Mac to develop React applications, and I've noticed that if I remove an import statement, I do not get any red-underlining like I am used to.

Any thoughts as to how I can get this functionality back?  I imagine its due to an Angular package I had installed on my previous workspace, that I no longer have.

Comment: I beleive you used TypeScript with Angular. Do you use TypeScript with React as well?

Comment: You should try using .jsx file. It will handle almost every typo bugs. In other cases, you have to wait until the project is finished building. That's the problem with javascript.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm using Javascript for React now, whereas I was using Typescript for Angular.  I can see how that's the discrepancy.

Answer (score 8):

@Matt Bierner gave a good advice to check [instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript), but after reading it I can say that the best option is to create or modify `jsconfig.json` by adding `"checkJs": true`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can create a jsconfig.json file at your root folder and add these compiler option. **chekJs** will check the javascript errors and **jsx** will check the errors inside the jsx. Well this worked for me as i was also not getting any highlights but with these options it worked for me.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",

      // these are just imports configuratoins
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
     "@src/*": ["src/*"],
     "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
     "@pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
    "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, VS Code only checks the syntax of JS files and will not complain about undefined variables like it does with TypeScript

You can follow [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript) to enable type checking in plain old JS files. The simplest approach is to add `//@ts-check` at the top of the file